# Kotlin Coroutine Launch inside another launch getting called sequentially

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have 2 suspend methods invoked via launch and both of those methods creates further coroutines via launch. I see the results are sequential. If I remove the second level launch, then I see that the operations are executed in parallel. Can someone throw light on why this isn't being run in async/parallel?

```
private suspend fun coroutineA() = coroutineScope {
    println("[${printThreadInfo()}] Starting coroutineA()")
    (1..10).forEach {
        launch {
            delay(1000)
            println("[${printThreadInfo()}] A$it")
        }
    }
}

private suspend fun coroutineB() = coroutineScope {
    println("[${printThreadInfo()}] Starting coroutineB()")
    (1..10).forEach {
        launch {
            delay(1000)
            println("[${printThreadInfo()}] B$it")
        }
    }
}


// -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug
fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        launch {
            println("[${printThreadInfo()}] Launching coroutineA")
            coroutineA()
        }
        launch {
            println("[${printThreadInfo()}] Launching coroutineB")
            coroutineB()
        }
    }
}
```

The result I see is:

```
[2020-11-20T07:53:17.749 Thread=main] Start of main()
[2020-11-20T07:53:17.859 Thread=main @coroutine#1] Launching launchMultipleCoroutines
[2020-11-20T07:53:17.866 Thread=main @coroutine#2] Launching coroutineA
[2020-11-20T07:53:17.868 Thread=main @coroutine#2] Starting coroutineA()
[2020-11-20T07:53:17.871 Thread=main @coroutine#3] Launching coroutineB
[2020-11-20T07:53:17.872 Thread=main @coroutine#3] Starting coroutineB()
[2020-11-20T07:53:18.878 Thread=main @coroutine#4] A1
[2020-11-20T07:53:18.878 Thread=main @coroutine#5] A2
[2020-11-20T07:53:18.878 Thread=main @coroutine#6] A3
[2020-11-20T07:53:18.879 Thread=main @coroutine#7] A4
[2020-11-20T07:53:18.879 Thread=main @coroutine#8] A5
[2020-11-20T07:53:18.879 Thread=main @coroutine#9] A6
[2020-11-20T07:53:18.879 Thread=main @coroutine#10] A7
[2020-11-20T07:53:18.879 Thread=main @coroutine#11] A8
[2020-11-20T07:53:18.880 Thread=main @coroutine#12] A9
[2020-11-20T07:53:18.880 Thread=main @coroutine#13] A10
[2020-11-20T07:53:18.880 Thread=main @coroutine#14] B1
[2020-11-20T07:53:18.880 Thread=main @coroutine#15] B2
[2020-11-20T07:53:18.880 Thread=main @coroutine#16] B3
[2020-11-20T07:53:18.880 Thread=main @coroutine#17] B4
[2020-11-20T07:53:18.881 Thread=main @coroutine#18] B5
[2020-11-20T07:53:18.881 Thread=main @coroutine#19] B6
[2020-11-20T07:53:18.881 Thread=main @coroutine#20] B7
[2020-11-20T07:53:18.881 Thread=main @coroutine#21] B8
[2020-11-20T07:53:18.881 Thread=main @coroutine#22] B9
[2020-11-20T07:53:18.881 Thread=main @coroutine#23] B10
```

whereas if I remove the launch() inside coroutineA and coroutineB, I see that the results looks like executed in parallel:

```
[2020-11-20T08:02:49.356 Thread=main @coroutine#2] Launching coroutineA
[2020-11-20T08:02:49.407 Thread=main @coroutine#2] Starting coroutineA()
[2020-11-20T08:02:49.415 Thread=main @coroutine#3] Launching coroutineB
[2020-11-20T08:02:49.415 Thread=main @coroutine#3] Starting coroutineB()
[2020-11-20T08:02:49.512 Thread=main @coroutine#2] A1
[2020-11-20T08:02:49.516 Thread=main @coroutine#3] B1
[2020-11-20T08:02:49.612 Thread=main @coroutine#2] A2
[2020-11-20T08:02:49.617 Thread=main @coroutine#3] B2
[2020-11-20T08:02:49.716 Thread=main @coroutine#2] A3
[2020-11-20T08:02:49.718 Thread=main @coroutine#3] B3
[2020-11-20T08:02:49.817 Thread=main @coroutine#2] A4
[2020-11-20T08:02:49.819 Thread=main @coroutine#3] B4
[2020-11-20T08:02:49.921 Thread=main @coroutine#2] A5
...
```

Comment: The problem is you are using `runBlocking` which is single threaded. And not yielding or let other coroutine run, i.e. coroutineScope will wait until its child finishes, and till that coroutineB won't execute as there are no more threads.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out that we need to use `launch(Dispatchers.Default)` to achieve the coroutine running in parallel.
Displaying the context helped in narrowing down.

```
[2020-11-20T08:47:47.858 Thread=main @coroutine#2] [[CoroutineId(2), "coroutine#2":StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@3d04a311, BlockingEventLoop@7a46a697]] Launching coroutineA
[2020-11-20T08:47:47.912 Thread=main @coroutine#2] [[CoroutineId(2), "coroutine#2":ScopeCoroutine{Active}@57fa26b7, BlockingEventLoop@7a46a697]] Starting coroutineA()
[2020-11-20T08:47:47.921 Thread=main @coroutine#3] Launching coroutineB
[2020-11-20T08:47:47.922 Thread=main @coroutine#3] [[CoroutineId(3), "coroutine#3":ScopeCoroutine{Active}@44e81672, BlockingEventLoop@7a46a697]] Starting coroutineB()
[2020-11-20T08:47:48.929 Thread=DefaultDispatcher-worker-6 @coroutine#17] [[CoroutineId(17), "coroutine#17":StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@7e782624, Dispatchers.Default]] B4
[2020-11-20T08:47:48.929 Thread=DefaultDispatcher-worker-5 @coroutine#4] [[CoroutineId(4), "coroutine#4":StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@28a58b8f, Dispatchers.Default]] A1
```

Adding the dispatcher type changes from blockingEvenLoop to standalone coroutine.